# How to color line from geojson in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, geojson

I have a problem with painting my line from geojson. When im getting polygon from geojson i haven't problems with painting them, but when i receive a lineString i couldn't do that.

This is example of code which painting my polygon but not lineString.

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle="red";
```

Thanks for Yours help.

Additional qustion is about posibility to draw gradient on this line. Is there any posiblity for that or no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to use`ctx.strokeStyle` in place of `ctx.fillStyle`.
[Here's the documentation at MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/strokeStyle)